# Android TV Leanback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

[image: layout I am trying to achieve]

I am new to Android TV development. I don't know which type of fragment to use.  I want two achieve layout similar to above screenshot as jiocinema. Somehow I have achieved it using a two xml fragments inside activity layout.  Second fragments loads screenshot after hitting an API so it loads after some time. As can be seen in the above screenshot I want the layout in two parts..top one with details and some buttons and the bottom one is a list of screenshots of that movie.

In my case the problem is, bottom list part takes the focus on loading this particular screen after that on pressing up button or any button it never loses focus and never goes on the top part.
**Note: below fragment loads asynchronously, as it hits an api for screenshot urls**

May be I haven't used proper fragments for this particular layout. Can someone point me to the code or help me out in deciding what to use for this kind of layout. As it can be achieved but navigation is the main thing.

code

activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/photo_label_box">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="com.DetailsActivityGame$Detalfragment"
        android:layout_height="200dp"></fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/row_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/detail_layout"
        android:name="com.DetailsActivityGame$SampleFragmentC"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the RowSupportFragment in V4 Support Fragment for desired output.

Divide layout into two parts layout with buttons, description and below scrolling layout(Represent by RowSupportFragment)

//----------------------detail_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/leader_background">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
  //your own layout design for buttons and description
</RelativeLayout>
<fragment
    android:name="FragmentScreenshots"
    android:id="@+id/screenshot_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

//----------------Detailfragment--------------------

```
public static class Detailfragment extends Fragment {
    public  Detailfragment(){ }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_layout, container, false);
        //————————your own implementation—————————————————————————
        return view;
     }
     public static class FragmentScreenshots extends RowsSupportFragment {
         private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter = null;
          public FragmentScreenshots() {
            mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ShadowRowPresenterSelector());
            setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
           }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //———————Provide data accordinally———————————
             List<ScreenshotItem> list;

             // Add a Related items row
            ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(
                    new ScreenshotCardPresenter(getActivity()));
            for (ScreenshotItem s:list)
            {
                listRowAdapter.add(s);
            }
            HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem("Screenshots");
            mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
            setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

            setOnItemViewClickedListener(new OnItemViewClickedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
                    if (item instanceof ScreenshotItem) {
                                                  }
                    else{
                                                }
                }
            });

            setOnItemViewSelectedListener(new OnItemViewSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item, RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void setExpand(boolean expand) {
            super.setExpand(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOnItemViewClickedListener(BaseOnItemViewClickedListener listener) {
            super.setOnItemViewClickedListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOnItemViewSelectedListener(BaseOnItemViewSelectedListener listener) {
            super.setOnItemViewSelectedListener(listener);
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `BrowseFragment` for your purpose. It is composed of a RowsFragment and a HeadersFragment.

A BrowseFragment renders the elements of its ObjectAdapter as a set of rows in a vertical list. The elements in this adapter must be subclasses of Row.

[This tutorial](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-2-85.html) can help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i dont need left drawer...still i can use it ?. i didn't tried that just because of the drawer

Comment: For that you have make customisation in your browsefragment.

Comment: I disagree.  If you don't need the left drawer (which is one of the main purposes / components of BrowseFragment), just use a RowsFragment.